PagedIterable<FileSystemItem> is always blocking
I am new to both Spring Webflux and Azure and I am not understanding what is going on here. I am attempting to check to see if a Data Lake container already exists. I do not understand why this is blocking. I have also tried many from this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/pagination) with the same results.
    public boolean checkIfFileSystemExists(String fileSystem) {
        return azureDataLakeClient.getDataLakeServiceClient().listFileSystems().stream().anyMatch(c -> fileSystem.equals(c.getName()));
    }

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-10
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-10
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2815) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at com.azure.core.util.paging.ContinuablePagedByIteratorBase.requestPage(ContinuablePagedByIteratorBase.java:102) ~[azure-core-1.49.0.jar:1.49.0]
    at com.azure.core.util.paging.ContinuablePagedByItemIterable$ContinuablePagedByItemIterator.<init>(ContinuablePagedByItemIterable.java:75) ~[azure-core-1.49.0.jar:1.49.0]
    at com.azure.core.util.paging.ContinuablePagedByItemIterable.iterator(ContinuablePagedByItemIterable.java:55) ~[azure-core-1.49.0.jar:1.49.0]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.spliterator(Iterable.java:101) ~[na:na]
    at com.azure.core.util.paging.ContinuablePagedIterable.stream(ContinuablePagedIterable.java:85) ~[azure-core-1.49.0.jar:1.49.0]
    at com.parsons.datamart.common.datalake.azure.writer.AzureDataLakeWriter.checkIfFileSystemExists(AzureDataLakeWriter.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at com.parsons.datamart.common.datalake.azure.writer.AzureDataLakeWriter.write(AzureDataLakeWriter.java:44) ~[main/:na]
    at com.parsons.datamart.ingest.web.WebClientIngestor.notifyIngest(WebClientIngestor.java:74) ~[main/:na]
    at com.parsons.datamart.ingest.web.WebClientIngestor.lambda$ingest$1(WebClientIngestor.java:37) ~[main/:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onNext(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2097) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:415) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:446) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:500) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:782) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1475) ~[netty-handler-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1338) ~[netty-handler-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1387) ~[netty-handler-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529) ~[netty-codec-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468) ~[netty-codec-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]


There is a section on that webpage describing an async way, did you try it too?

subscribe() is not available as an option, so I was unable to try that.

Maybe you forgot to add a dependency with async client? The docs suggests that you have to use this implementation, not the blocking one.

@IgorArtamonov Thank you very much. I misread the javadoc on the DataLakeServiceClientBuilder, but after you mentioned the async way I dug further down and saw that there were two ways to build it. It is not so much that I forgot, it was my lack of knowledge. I am still trying to wrap my head around this paradigm.


PagedIterable is always blocking
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are  blocking, which  is  not  supported  in  thread  reactor-http-nio-10  Caused  by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are  blocking, which  is  not  supported  in  thread  reactor-http-nio-10

The above error indicates, the block() method is being used, which is a blocking action that is not supported by the current thread.
I agree with Igor Artamonov's Comment, To fix the issue of blocking calls in a non-blocking environment such as Spring WebFlux, use the Azure SDK's asynchronous, non-blocking methods.
it seems like you are using the synchronous version of the Azure Data Lake Storage client. To avoid blocking, you can switch to the asynchronous version of the client.
Based on your code, it indicates that you are using the synchronous Azure Data Lake Storage client. To avoid blocking, use the asynchronous version of the client.
Here is the latest dependency of Azure Data Lake Storage client.
Pom.XML
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
     <artifactId>azure-storage-file-datalake</artifactId>
     <version>12.19.0</version>
 </dependency>

You can use the below asynchronous code to get the list of file systems with monotype to represent the result.
public Mono<Boolean> checkIfFileSystemExists(String fileSystem) {
    return dataLakeServiceAsyncClient.listFileSystems()
        .filter(c -> fileSystem.equals(c.getName()))
        .hasElements();
}

Mono returns true if there are elements in the filtered Flux, and false if not.
Reference:
DataLakeServiceAsyncClient Class | Microsoft Learn
